# Shared library from C and C++ object files

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

Can I create a shared library from the C and C++ object files?. If possible where should I use it? (in C/C++ applications or both).

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to do this from source files (as per the title) or object files (as per the question body)?

Comment: not necessarily... they have to be "compiled as shared"

Answer (score 0):

You can create shared library from *.o* file (Create from C or C++ file) and use it into C or C++ application.

There is [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) and [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) tutorials about shared library that show how compile shared library and how use it.

If you have any question about it, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not all situation you can do that. If you have source code, you can compile them as:

```
gcc -fPIC exam.c -o exam.o
gcc -shared exam.o -o libexam.so
```

PIC means position-independent code. And if a object file is compiled with -fPIC, it can be used to create shared lib.